# Java Stack stuck

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I'm new to Java. Please help me understand Java.

I have trouble understanding some my teacher's code about "stacks."

The code bellow is for my class `Person`. My question is what does  `private Person next;` mean?  Why this variable such with class name ?  What is this class doing?

```
public class Person {
    private String _name, _address;
    private int _id;
    private Person next; // what is this mean and do 

    public Person(String a, String b, int c){
        this._name = a;
        this._address = b;
        this._id = c;
    }
    public Person(){

    }

    public String getname(){
        return this._name;
    }

    public String getaddress(){
        return this._address;
    }

    public int getid(){
        return this._id;
    }

    public person getnext(){
        return this.next;
    }

    public void setname(String a){
        this._name = a;
    }

    public void setaddress(String a){
        this._address = a;
    }

    public void setid(int a){
        this._id = a;
    }

    public void setnext(person a){
        this.next = a;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Person{"+ "Name = " + _name +", Address" + _address +", Id = " + _id +'}';
    }
}
```

And this is my code for main class. In this main class I can't understand what `private static  Person HeadStack` contains and what it will do. Why is HeadStack keyword always used in method "pop", "push", and "print"?

```
public class mainmahasisswa {


    private static  Person HeadStack; // what is this mean & do 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        push();
        push();
        push();
        print();
        pop();
        print();
        pop();
        print();
        push();
        print();
    }

        private static  Person setdata(){
        person pr = new person();
        String name, address;
        int id;

        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name : ");
        address = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Address : ");
        id = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("id : "));

        pr.setname(name);
        pr.setaddress(address);
        pr.setid(id);
        pr.setnext(null);

        return pr;
    }

    private static void pop(){
            if (HeadStack != null){
                person aa ;
                aa = HeadStack.getnext();
                HeadStack = aa;
            }
            else{

                System.out.println();
            }
        }

    private static void push(){
        person x = setdata();         
        if(HeadStack != null){
            x.setnext(HeadStack);  
            HeadStack = x;
        }
        else{
            HeadStack = x;
        }
    }

    private static void print(){
        if(HeadStack != null ){
            person y = HeadStack;
            while(y != null){
                System.out.println(y.toString());

                y = y.getnext();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW `String _name` is a reference to an object just like `person next` is.

Comment: Please note the the recommended naming convention for java class names is: "Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.". See [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html). So in your case `public class Person {` is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it as a link in the chain `private person next` provides a link to the "next" `person` object in this chain or `null` if it does not exist.

```
private person next; // what is this mean and do
```

This a declaration that says next is a type of `person`, which is initially assigned `null`

This...

```
private static  person HeadStack; // what is this mean & do
```

is simply a declaration that says `HeadStack` is type of `person` which is `static`, meaning that it doesn't rely on particular instance of any class to be accessed.

Take a look at [Language Basics: Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) and [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

> why this HeadStack keyword always used in method "pop","push","print"

The object represents the first link in the chain

Comment: Still don't understand, about why person in (private person next) can be variable. Like int to contain number.

Comment: Why not?  `person` is just a type of object, it's not an instance, so the declaration goes something like `{modifier} {type} {name}`, which says that `next` is a type of `person` and is `private` to the `person` class